# Is the inverse of MST cut property true? Why?

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs, minimum-spanning-tree, spanning-trees

If we partition the nodes of a graph into sets A and B, there is an edge *e* of weight larger than any other edge crossing the cut between A and B, *e* would never be in the minimum spanning tree?

Comment: Each spanning tree includes an edge that crosses the cut between $A$ and $B$. That edge, in fact, must be of weight not larger than any other edge crossing the cut between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Could you please copy the exact statement of the cut property as you have seen and paste it in the question? Thanks you.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the case.

If an edge $e$ is a bridge in the graph, then every MST has to include $e$. There can exist some cut in which $e$ is the heaviest edge, but this does not change the fact that $e$ must be included (there is some other cut in which $e$ is the only - and therefore the lighest - edge).

Comment: Nice catch on the corner case. However, this answer breaks the truth symmetry of the cut property and its inverse. Hence, I would not prefer to teach the version of cut property and its inverse implied in this answer to my students.

Answer (score -1):

There is some ambiguity  in the question. I would like to present some detailed versions, where we can enjoy both the cut property and its inverse.

---

Let $G$ be a connected, edge-weighted undirected graph, $C$ be a cut of $G$ and $e$ be an edge that crosses $C$.

**The cut property of Minimum Spanning Trees (MSTs) for $(G, C, e)$**: If, for any other edge $e'$ that crosses $C$, the weight of $e$ is not larger that of $e'$, then there is an MST of $G$ that contains $e$.

Here is the inverse proposition.

**The inverse cut property of Minimum Spanning Trees (MSTs) for $(G, C, e)$**: If there exists an edge $e'$ that crosses $C$ such that the weight of $e$ is larger than that of $e'$, then there is no MST of $G$ that contains $e$.

The inverse proposition is true. We can prove it by contradiction. Suppose there is MST $M$ that contains $e$. We can replace $e$ with $e'$ to obtain a new spanning tree. This new spanning tree has less weight than $M$, which is false since $M$ has the least weight.

---

Here is a different version of the cut property.

**(*Second version*) The cut property of Minimum Spanning Trees (MSTs) for $(G, C, e)$**: If, for any other edge $e'$ that crosses $C$, the weight of $e$ is smaller than that of $e'$, then every MST of $G$ contains $e$.

Here is the inverse proposition.

**(*Second version*) The inverse cut property of Minimum Spanning Trees (MSTs) for $(G, C, e)$**: If there exists an edge $e'$ that crosses $C$ such that the weight of $e$ is not smaller than that of $e'$, then there is an MST of $G$ that does not contain $e$.

The inverse proposition is true. We can prove it directly.

- If there is MST $M$ that does not contains $e$, our proof is done.
- Otherwise, let $M$ be an MST that does contain $e$.  We can replace $e$ with $e'$ to obtain a new spanning tree, which does not contain $e$. This new spanning tree has the same weight as $M$. Hence, the new spanning tree is an MST, too. $\quad\checkmark$

Comment: The answer is wrong. The only guarantee that some edge $e$ is not in any MST of $G$ is that for *any* cut $C$ such that $e$ crosses $C$, $e$ is strictly not the lightest edge to do so. There is no such guarantee when looking at just one arbitrary cut.

Comment: The problem with your proofs is that you tacitly assume that one can replace any edge in a spanning tree with any other edge and end up with another spanning tree, which is not true in general.

Comment: Here is another formal version of the cut property, given a connected, edge-weighted undirected graph $G$ and an edge $e$.  "If there exists a cut $C$ such that $e$ is one of the lightest cuts crossing $C$, then there is an MST that contains $e$". Its inverse, "If there does not exist a cut $C$ such that $e$ is one of the lightest cuts crossing $C$, then there is no MST that contains $e$", is also true.

Comment: Yes, your last version of the inverse cut property: "If there does not exist a cut $C$..." is true. However, the version that was asked about, and the versions in your answer, are not true.

Comment: I think it's important to point out your error here, as if this property were true, this would imply an $O(E)$ algorithm for MST, at least in the case where all weights are different:

Comment: Since, for any two edges in a graph, you can find a cut where those two edges are included, the algorithm just takes two edges at a time and throws away the heaviest one. Then you end up with *one* edge, the lightest one. Oh no...

Comment: It looks like I did make a blunder. So I will update my answer with the third version, the correct version.

Comment: @JohnL. you have not updated your answer with the correct version, leaving this question unanswered thus far